# Can a Multi line text box in c# hide some text elements and show when you click on a text box please see example?

Tags: c#, textbox, multiline

[image: Above picture is what details are to be shown when you click the check box and what is to be hidden when its not checked. I have no clue how to do this and I am sure its simple. But any help would be appreciated as I am pretty new to this. Thanks]
above are what details to be shown when you click the check box and what is to be hidden when its not checked.  I have no clue how to do this and I am sure its simple.  But any help would be appreciated as I am pretty new to this.  Thanks

Comment: First you should try doing it and if you still can't then come back here with your code for help. We're not here to do your homework

Comment: I have tried and am struggling with it which is why i am asking for some help or guidance.  I am not looking for the answer but a way to solve the solution.  Any ideas or pointers in the right place would be good as I am really lost on this.

Comment: You will have to utilize the checkbox CheckedChanged event. In the event handler you could store the text in a local variable, modify that variable as necessary and then set it back

Comment: Thanks I was using the checkedChanged event but I was using it wrong.  I was not setting a local variable in there.  Thank you

Comment: Glad you got it sorted, I'm sure you could have done it on your own if you gave it some more thought!

Comment: The interface you are trying to reproduce seems to be very similar to a tree view. You could have the details as child nodes of the parent date node. This provides an easy to use UI for expanding details for specific date nodes. Just a suggestion. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using a RichTextBox, you save all the lines to a variable of type array of strings, and you save the lines that contain 'Deposit" in an other variable of the same type.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string[] LinesWithDetails;
    string[] LinesWithOutDetails;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinesWithDetails = richTextBox1.Lines;
        LinesWithOutDetails = richTextBox1.Lines.Where(l => l.Contains("Deposit")).ToArray();

        HideDetails();
    }

    private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (checkBox1.Checked)
            ShowDetails();
        else
            HideDetails();
    }

    private void ShowDetails()
    {
        richTextBox1.Lines = LinesWithDetails;
    }
    private void HideDetails()
    {
        richTextBox1.Lines = LinesWithOutDetails;
    }


}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked well - i was able to use that in my solution as I was not getting anything to work earlier. Thanks again